# Python3 Multiprocessing Pool calling initializer infinitely when accessing Lock

Tags: python, multiprocessing, locking

I want to use `Lock` in the child process to process a file. When I access `Lock` in the initializer, `Pool` makes infinite recursive call to the initializer.

```
from multiprocessing import Lock, get_context


class MyClass(object):

    @classmethod
    def run_mp(cls, jobs):
        context = get_context('spawn')
        w_lock = Lock()
        with context.Pool(1, initializer=cls._mp_init, initargs=(w_lock, )) as pool:
            res = pool.map(cls._execute_job, jobs)
            pool.close()

    @classmethod
    def _mp_init(cls, w_lock):
        # global weights_lock
        # weights_lock = w_lock
        print('weights lock')
        print(w_lock)  # this line causes infinite calls to this method

    @classmethod
    def _execute_job(cls, job):
        pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    jobs = [1]
    mc = MyClass()
    mc.run_mp(jobs)
```

**Expected Output**

I get the expected output on my local machine - mac_os, python3.7

```
weights lock
<Lock(owner=unknown)>
```

**Incorrect Output**

When I run this on linux instance on gcloud (linux 18.04, python 3.6), I get

```
weights lock
weights lock
weights lock
weights lock
weights lock
# ... infinitely
```

If I comment out `print(w_lock)` in the `_init_mp` method, then the output is again as expected

```
weight lock
```

So basically, when I try to access `w_lock`, it goes into an infinite recursive call of `_init_mp`.

I've tried running this on different glcoud instances with the same behavior.

I cannot understand why accessing the lock would cause such a behavior on linux. Any explanations?

Comment: This behavior does NOT happen when using `fork` method,  but with `spawn` and `forkserver`

Comment: The lock needs to have the same context, so you need `w_lock = context.Lock()`. As a side note, remove `pool.close()`, that's what Pool's context-manager is already doing for you.

Comment: That was it! Thanks! I'm still stumped why it works fine on MacOs and not on Linux. Does the context work differently between the two?

Comment: When you are on Python 3.8+, macOS already uses "spawn" as default so you don't end up trying to mix two different start methods like with trying this on Linux where "fork" still is the default.

Comment: Ah I see. That answers it. Thanks