# Python multiprocessing `spawn` start method throwing `context has already been set` Runtime error

Tags: python, pytorch, multiprocessing, spawn

I am trying to set the `multiprocessing.set_start_method()` to `spawn` mode in my `if __name__ == '__main__'` code.

Running this on `ubunu` `VERSION="18.04.6 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"`. I have to set this to `spawn` mode in order for my pytorch inference to work.

But when i run the program, i am getting the below error.

```
Error in Main function : %s Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/multi-process-testing/main.py", line 22, in <module>
    set_start_method('spawn')
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/conda-pv-pytorch-2/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/context.py", line 243, in set_start_method
    raise RuntimeError('context has already been set')

RuntimeError: context has already been set
```

When i try to use the `force=True`, i am getting the `leaked semaphores` error/warning and my program is not executing.

```
(conda-pv-pytorch-2) ubuntu@ip-172-31-22-56:~/multi-process-testing$ /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/conda-pv-pytorch-2/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/resource_tracker.py:216: UserWarning: resource_tracker: There appear to be 2 leaked semaphore objects to clean up at shutdown
  warnings.warn('resource_tracker: There appear to be %d '
```

My `main.py` looks like below.

```
from consumer import ConsumerVideoHandlerProcess
from producer import ProducerVideoHandlerProcess
from sm import SharedMemoryHandler
from torch.multiprocessing import set_start_method, get_start_method, freeze_support
import multiprocessing as mp
import traceback
import sys, os


shared_mem_handler = SharedMemoryHandler()
shared_memory_object_tuple = shared_mem_handler.create_shared_memory()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:

        ## Creating shared memory handler to hold the image frames
        #ctx = mp.get_context('spawn')
        #global shared_memory_object_tuple
        # mp.set_executable(os.path.join(sys.exec_prefix, 'pythonw.exe'))
        set_start_method('spawn', force=True)

        ### Calling Producer class process

        producer_reader_process = ProducerVideoHandlerProcess(shared_memory_object_tuple)
        producer_reader_process.start()

        ### Calling Consumer class process
        consumer_reader_process = ConsumerVideoHandlerProcess(shared_memory_object_tuple)
        consumer_reader_process.start()

        producer_reader_process.join()
        consumer_reader_process.join()

        ## Cleanup

        producer_reader_process.terminate()
        del producer_reader_process
        consumer_reader_process.terminate()
        del consumer_reader_process
        del shared_memory_object_tuple
        print("Main Process completed successfully")
    except (ValueError, Exception):
        print("Error in Main function : %s", traceback.format_exc())

#if __name__ == '__main__':
    #set_start_method('spawn')
#    main()
```

I also moved entire code under `if __name__ == '__main__'` to a separate function `main()` and just called the `main()` method by setting the `set_start_method('spawn')` from `if __name__ == '__main__'`.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    set_start_method('spawn')
    main()
```

But this also throwing the same error. And also tried the below lines of code by getting the context and this also did not work.

```
ctx = mp.get_context('spawn')
producer_reader_process = ctx.Process(target=ProducerVideoHandlerProcess, args=(shared_memory_object_tuple,))
producer_reader_process.start()
consumer_reader_process = ctx.Process(target=ConsumerVideoHandlerProcess, args=(shared_memory_object_tuple,))
consumer_reader_process.start()
```

Could you let me know how can i fix this issue. Thank you in advance.

**Update 1**

I changed the code to below as per suggestions from @CharchitAgarwal.

```
from consumer import ConsumerVideoHandlerProcess
from producer import ProducerVideoHandlerProcess
from sm import SharedMemoryHandler
from multiprocessing import set_start_method, get_start_method, freeze_support
import traceback

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #freeze_support()
    set_start_method('spawn')
    print('Start method already set: ', get_start_method())

shared_mem_handler = SharedMemoryHandler()
shared_memory_object_tuple = shared_mem_handler.create_shared_memory()

try:
        producer_reader_process = ProducerVideoHandlerProcess(shared_memory_object_tuple)
        producer_reader_process.start()

        consumer_reader_process = ConsumerVideoHandlerProcess(shared_memory_object_tuple)
        consumer_reader_process.start()

        producer_reader_process.join()
        consumer_reader_process.join()

        ## Cleanup

        producer_reader_process.terminate()
        del producer_reader_process
        consumer_reader_process.terminate()
        del consumer_reader_process
        del shared_memory_object_tuple

        print("Main Process completed successfully")

except (ValueError, Exception):
        print("Error in Main function : %s", traceback.format_exc())
```

But the shared memory is not getting updated properly. It is always showing a numpy array with all `zeros`.  The producer class is generating a numpy array with non zero values and is placing in the shared memory. But the consumer class is getting all zeros when it is accessing the shared memory.

And at the end getting the below error.

```
Main Process completed successfully
(conda-pv-pytorch-2) ubuntu@ip-172-31-22-56:~/multi-process-testing$ /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/conda-pv-pytorch-2/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/resource_tracker.py:216: UserWarning: resource_tracker: There appear to be 2 leaked semaphore objects to clean up at shutdown
  warnings.warn('resource_tracker: There appear to be %d '
```

**Upate 2**

Tried different options to see how to fix this issue. Here is the minimalistic code that we can use to reproduce. Appreciate if someone can suggest a solution.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Lock, set_start_method, Array
import numpy as np
import random
import time

def create_a_dummy_frame():
    count = random.randint(1, 50)
    shape = [1, 4]
    frame = (np.ones(shape) * count)
    return frame

def modify_array_1(sharedarray, a_buffer_arrray, shape):
        ### Acquire the lock in the 1st  process
        sharedarray.acquire()
        print("Address in the 1st process : ", id(sharedarray))
        image_frame = create_a_dummy_frame()
        np.copyto(a_buffer_arrray, image_frame)

        print("a --- {}".format(a_buffer_arrray))

def modify_array_2(sharedarray, b_buffer_arrray, shape):
        time.sleep(1)
        print("Address in the 2nd process : ", id(sharedarray))
        b_buffered_array = b_buffer_arrray.astype("uint8").copy()
        print("b --- {}".format(b_buffered_array))
        ### Release the lock in the 2nd process
        sharedarray.release()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    set_start_method('spawn')  ### spwan start method.
    #set_start_method('fork')  ### default fork method in unix.
    lock = Lock()
    image_frame_shape = [1, 4]
    shared_memory_array = Array('d', 4, lock=lock)
    buffered_array = np.frombuffer(shared_memory_array.get_obj(), dtype='d').reshape(image_frame_shape)

    p1 = Process(target=modify_array_1, args=(shared_memory_array, buffered_array, image_frame_shape))
    p1.start()

    p2 = Process(target=modify_array_2, args=(shared_memory_array, buffered_array, image_frame_shape))
    p2.start()

    p1.join()
    p1.join()
    #print(list(shared_memory_array))
    #print(list(buffered_array))
```

In the `main` method, if i use `set_start_method('spawn')`, the output is as below.

```
(conda-pv-pytorch-2) ubuntu@ip-11-22-33-44:~/multi-process-testing$ python3 test1.py
Address in the 1st process :  140169076553664
a --- [[9. 9. 9. 9.]]
Address in the 2nd process :  140534970750912
b --- [[0 0 0 0]]
```

Clearly two processes are not using the same shared array.

If I use the default `fork` start method, i can see the same output.

```
(conda-pv-pytorch-2) ubuntu@ip-11-22-33-44:~/multi-process-testing$ python3 test1.py
Address in the 1st process :  140170642829904
a --- [[22. 22. 22. 22.]]
Address in the 2nd process :  140170642829904
b --- [[22 22 22 22]]
```

Here the address for the shared array is same in both the processes.

How can i make sure the array variable can be accessed in both the processes when i use the `spawn` method.

I tried the suggestion from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64083073/python3-multiprocessing-pool-calling-initializer-infinitely-when-accessing-lock) as well by creating a `context` object, but that also did not help.

```
context = get_context('spawn')
    lock = context.Lock()
    image_frame_shape = [1, 4]
    shared_memory_array = context.Array('d', 4, lock=lock)
    buffered_array = np.frombuffer(shared_memory_array.get_obj(), dtype='d').reshape(image_frame_shape)

    p1 = context.Process(target=modify_array_1, args=(shared_memory_array, buffered_array, image_frame_shape))
    p1.start()

    p2 = context.Process(target=modify_array_2, args=(shared_memory_array, buffered_array, image_frame_shape))
    p2.start()
```

Appreciate your help.

Comment: start method can only be set once, which implies that your code before the `if __name__...` block is setting their own start method. Check the libraries you are importing if they do that (they shouldn't be, if they are it should be a bug), and the `sm` package as well. The leaked semaphores warning seems to be relevant to this line in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#contexts-and-start-methods) `...if a process was killed by a signal there may be some “leaked” resources`.

Comment: So it seems the leaked shared memory blocks are a result of unsuccessfully setting the start method

Comment: Thank you @CharchitAgarwal - I commented out all the lines in the `if __name__` section except `set_start_method('spawn')`.

Comment: The `sm.py` file has the below contents.

```
import torch.multiprocessing as multi_processing
import numpy as np

class SharedMemoryHandler:
        def __init__(self):
            #self.image_frame_shape = [480, 640]
            self.image_frame_shape = [5, 5]
            print("shared memory initialized")

        def create_shared_memory(self):
            type_code = "d"
            size = int(np.prod(self.image_frame_shape))
            frame_lock = multi_processing.Lock()
```

Comment: If i have `frame_lock = multi_processing.Lock()`, then i am getting the `RuntimeError: context has already been set`. If i comment out this line, the program is executing fine and the context is setting to `spawn` method. No idea why creating the `Lock()` causing this? Any suggestions?

Comment: using queues, pipes, locks, etc implicitly uses a context object to start them. I guess it also means a context is set during such a process (these objects would have likely not been compatible with others from another context anyway). You can do one thing. Right after the imports in your main.py, have another `if __name__...` block, and set the start method there, before you call anything else. I think that should fix the issue

Comment: I have updated the post with latest code that i tried based on your suggestions @CharchitAgarwal. Could you pls check this once.

Comment: Created the minimalistic code to reproduce the issue that i am facing. Please see in the `## Update 2` section of the post. Appreciate the help. Thank you.